# How to ungroup the grouped lists?

Tags: python

I have list of nested lists:

```
non_linear_list = [['testtest', '2020-06-17 12:40:23', 12.0000000000000, '20 USt', 2.0, 'Postage', '0'], 
                  ['testtest', '2020-06-17 12:40:23', 1.00000000000000, '10 USt', 0.09, 'Bad Debt', '0']]
```

I would like to ungroup these lists so that they look as **following**:

```
['testtest', '2020-06-17 12:40:23', 12.0000000000000, '20 USt', 2.0, 'Postage', '0'], 
['testtest', '2020-06-17 12:40:23', 1.00000000000000, '10 USt', 0.09, 'Bad Debt', '0']
```

I am trying to use following code to achieve that:

```
    print([val for sublist in non_linear_list for val in sublist])
```

But with this code I nest all the lists and get only one list:

```
['testtest', '2020-06-17 12:40:23', 12.0000000000000, '20 USt', 2.0, 'Postage', '0', 'testtest', '2020-06-17 12:40:23', 1.00000000000000, '10 USt', 0.09, 'Bad Debt', '0']
```

Can anyone help me on how to achieve the correct result?

Comment: If you know the exact number of nested lists, you can just use destructuring like this: `[first_list, second_list] = non_linear_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is just about *printing* the lists without the surrounding `[...]`, the easiest way would be a loop:

```
for x in non_linear_list:
    print(x)
```

Or if you prefer a single line, you can use `print(*...)`. Like with the loop, the `*` means "print each *part* of the list, not the list as a whole".

```
print(*non_linear_list, sep="\n")
```

If you actually want to "un-group" the list, as noted in comments, you can assign them to two (or more) variables (and then print them, or do whatever else you want to do with them):

```
a, b = non_linear_list
print(a)
print(b)
```

Each way, the output is

```
['testtest', '2020-06-17 12:40:23', 12.0, '20 USt', 2.0, 'Postage', '0']
['testtest', '2020-06-17 12:40:23', 1.0, '10 USt', 0.09, 'Bad Debt', '0']
```

Comment: thank you. I decided to actually ungroup each list of lists and append to a new list.